# C/Glib, am I truncating this gchar array properly?

Tags: c, string, free, glib

I'm attempted to refactor/repair a function, and did I do this truncation correctly?  If not how should this generally be done?  Was especially wondering about potential leaks.

```
void process_entry(GMenuTreeEntry *entry)
{
    char *name = g_strdup (gmenu_tree_entry_get_name(entry));
    char *exec = g_strdup (gmenu_tree_entry_get_exec(entry));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(exec) - 1; i++) {
        if (exec[i] == '%')
        {
            switch (exec[i+1]) {
                case 'f': case 'F':
                case 'u': case 'U':
                case 'd': case 'D':
                case 'n': case 'N':
                case 'i': case 'c': case 'k': case 'v': case 'm':
                    exec[i-1] = '\0';
                    i++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    g_printf("<item label=\"%s\">\n", g_strjoinv("&amp;", g_strsplit(name,"&",0))),
    g_printf("<action name=\"Execute\"><command>%s</command></action>\n", exec),
    g_printf("</item>\n");

    g_free(name);
    g_free(exec);
}
```

This is for some GPL code, so your help is very much appreciated.  I'm still very new to C in general, and glib I'm literally brand new.

Comment: Of course you'll unit test this function before submitting it anywhere. Don't be satisfied with just these, but a basic test would necessarily test against null, empty, "%a", "a%", "a", "%". I would expect three of those to segfault. Yes certainly there are leaks, right where you're thinking there are leaks. But yes, inserting a '\0' is a perfectly cromulent way to truncate a C string.

Comment: ptomato answered the truncation part well.  As for leaks, you are leaking the return values of both g_strjoinv and g_strsplit.  You should save the results to a temporary variable, then call g_printf with that value, then call g_free and g_strfreev on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gchar` is exactly the same as `char`, so whatever you do here applies to regular C strings as well.

When you call `free()` or `g_free()` on a string, it doesn't compute the `strlen()` to find out how much memory to free; it frees however much memory was initially allocated at that address. Otherwise, you could never free pointers that didn't specify the length of their allocated memory somewhere. So it's safe to truncate the string.